# Plugin being blocked by CSP - even at localhost

Tags: content-security-policy, banno-digital-toolkit

How are we to have plugins that aren't hosted on the same domains as Banno actually load as widgets? Every time that I try something that isn't localhost it gives me a CSP error. And even when I, as the documentation says, simply include *another* redirect URI that is at the domain (https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/) it *still* doesn't work. And even then some localhost URL's dont' work, for example a dotnet application serving at port 64311 is blocked by the CSP, but a Node app that I serve at port 3000 is not blocked.

Comment: Please share the CSP error message.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. It is below (just a URL I was using to test the thing);

```Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://auth2-dev.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration (“frame-src”).```

Comment: The super puzzling part of this to me is that I even see `https://auth2-dev.azurewebsites.net` listed in the `frame-src` attribute of the CSP.

Comment: @OliverHader, found the problem, because of the way that JH creates the list of URLs in its CSP (literally aggregating together every client's URL into a big list) if somebody (not me) screws up and types in an invalid URL, like `http://localhost;8080` (not a typo) then it prematurely ends the attribute FOR EVERYBODY. I had to Tweet them because, ya know, no "real" support protocol.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like we may have to fix that particular CSP entry. But otherwise, sounds like you got past that stumbling block.

Comment: I only got past it by using a proxy to completely remove the CSP response header, it's still VERY busted.

Comment: Just for clarity, some client DID use `http://localhost;8080` and the CSP is being truncated after the `;` (since it's the delimiter for CSP directives).

Comment: @charlesread we've repaired the CSP so there is no longer an entry with a semicolon (`http://localhost;8080`). This should work be working again.